# How to implement fixed bottom in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

With css.

Please don't refer me to another link.

**EDIT**

Make something always at the bottom of viewport no matter how you scroll the bar.

Comment: This question is very broad. can you elaborate?

Comment: So basically you want something to the extent of how(for example) facebook has at the bottom of it's page the little chatback/notifications thing?

Comment: how about using something like firebug to see how facebook does it rather than give people(trying to help) snide comments, and down voting their suggestions in an effort to help you with YOUR problem

Comment: +1 Because of the pretentious people on this site down voting badly worded posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems specifically with IE6 - consider using a resets script.  It will make your life much, much easier.  There are lots of different flavours of reset script out there, so do a bit of research and to find one that you like.  Personally, I find that yahoo produce one that's fit for purpose.

The thinking behind using a resets script is:

1. Each browser applies a set of
   default styles and properties,
   before any user style sheet is even
   loaded.
2. A lot of the differences between the
   way a page renders are due to the
   inconsistencies between these
   defaults.
3. If we could find a way to 'flatten
   the ground' before we begin
   building, life would be easier

A resets script performs that flattening - and IE6 can be dealt with in a much more logical way.

The obligatory link ;)

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

**Solution**

Bearing in mind the use of this resets script, I offer you the following solution.

As you're probably aware, IE6 doesn't support position:fixed.

To solve the problem you can make use of the following snippet:

```
<style>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

div#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

* html div#fixed-bottom {
    position: absolute;
}

</style>
```

Which should be applied to a document containing the following elements within it's `<body></body>`:

```
    <div id="fixed-bottom">
        <p>
            I'm at the bottom
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>
            Your content here.....
        </p>
    </div>
```

This should work because:

1. IE6 treats height in the same way that most browsers treat max-height.  The overflow auto will allow content to flow (with scrollbars) if the content carries on past the height of the browser viewport.
2. The '*' hack is used for simplity - it makes sure that IE6 applies 'position:absolute;' rather than 'position:fixed'.  **You should use conditional comments to provide specific CSS for IE6.**
3. Note that this solution will only work when IE6 is set to use 'strict mode'.  This can be set explicitly by choosing an appropriate doctype; for example:

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by "standars mode"?

Comment: Apologies, it was late when I wrote this.  IE6 can operate in two different modes .. one is called quirks mode and the other is known as strict mode.  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: @mask, I don't think down-voting, and deselected my answer as accepted means you're grateful.  As others have said, the way you behave on stack overflow leaves a lot of be desired.

Comment: btw - if anyone's looking at this answer and is wondering if it works, it does.